# File loading in java in Intellij idea plugin development

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am making a Spring Boot generator plugin and I wanna load in some template files with Velocity and/or Java. Preferable Java.

Now, the problem is, that I just cant figure out how to read in a *.vm template file in Java and convert it to a String variable.

So, here in my screenshot, I wanna load my "java_dto.vm", for example in with Java so that its content get converted to a String.

[Folder structure and files of plugin I am developing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4TaW.png)

This is how my Java_dto.vm file looks like:

```
package $dtoPackage;
public class $entityName#[[Dto]]# {
    public $entityName#[[Dto]]#() {

  }
}
```

I tried some things out in a normal Java class to load in a file which was successful.
But in the plugin itself now, I can't get this working.

So, this is NOT my plugin but the example I tried it in out.

[Project structure of tryout code to load in a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y62iZ.png)

With the code i tried all out and all worked.

```
`
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {
        // Determine where the input file is; assuming it's in the same 
           directory as the jar
        String fileName = "java_dto.vm";
        File jarFile = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain()
        .getCodeSource().getLocation()
        .toURI().getPath());           
        String inputFilePath = jarFile + File.separator + 
        "com\\tutorialspoint\\templates\\" + fileName;

        Path path = Paths.get(inputFilePath);
        String stringFromFile = 
        java.nio.file.Files.lines(path).collect(Collectors.joining());

        Path path2 = Paths.get(inputFilePath);

        String stringFromFile2 = new 
        String(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(path2));

        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(new 
        File(inputFilePath));

        try {

            // Read in the contents of the input file in a single gulp
            FileChannel fc = inStream.getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, 
            fc.size());

          System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            inStream.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //---------

    try {
        // Determine where the input file is; assuming it's in the same 
        directory as the jar
        String fileName = "java_dto.vm";
        File jarFile = new 
        File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
        .getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        String inputFilePath = jarFile + File.separator +
        "com\\tutorialspoint\\templates\\" + fileName;

        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(
        new File(inputFilePath));

        try {

            // Read in the contents of the input file in a single gulp
            FileChannel fc = inStream.getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(
             FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

          System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            inStream.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //---------

    try {
        // Determine where the input file is; assuming it's in the same directory as the jar
        String fileName = "java_dto.vm";
        File jarFile = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain()
        .getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        String inputFilePath = jarFile.getParent() + File.separator + 
        "untitled1\\com\\tutorialspoint\\" + fileName;
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(
                                new File(inputFilePath));

        try {

            // Read in the contents of the input file in a single gulp
            FileChannel fc = inStream.getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(
            FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

            // Do something with the read in data
            System.out.println("-----------");
            // hier wordt content uitgeprint

        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            inStream.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Map<String, String> valuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
    valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
    String templateString = "The ${animal} jumped over the ${target}.";

    System.out.println("templateString is: ");
    System.out.println(templateString);

    StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(valuesMap);
    String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);

    String s = new StringBuilder()
            .append("line1\n")
            .append("line2\n")
            .append("line3\n")
            .toString();
    System.out.println(s);

    String ss = new StringBuilder()
            .append("package $dtoPackage;")
            .append("\n")
            .append("\n")
            .append("public class $entityName#[[Dto]]# {")
            .append("\n")
            .append("\n")
            .append("public void haha() { ")
            .append("\n")
            .append("\n")
            .append("}")
            .append("\n")
            .append("}").toString();
    System.out.println(ss);

    String java_test = "package ${dtoPackage};" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "public class ${entityName}#[[Dto]]# {" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            " public void haha() { " +
            "\n" +
            " } " +
            " \n " +
            "}";

    Map<String, String> valuesTest = new HashMap<String, String>();
    valuesTest.put("dtoPackage", "com.filip.springboot.dto");
    valuesTest.put("entityName", "Test");

    StringSubstitutor subtest = new StringSubstitutor(valuesTest);
    String resolvedStringTest = subtest.replace(java_test);

    }
 }
```

`

Does anybody know this can be fixed/solved to use in a plugin for intellij idea? So no filechooser dialog, the name is already known and location also (in the templates folder).

Thanks already for your attention.

If something is not clear, let me know please.

Filip

Comment: Same question here, hav you found any way to do this?